# savon (SOAP:Server) No handlers could be found for unmarshalling the SOAP body payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

***Objective***

Build Soap call via savon v2

***What I tried :***

my soap call RQ , this is what given in the documentation

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ TimeStamp="2012-04-18T07:30:42.663Z" Target="Production" Version="1.0" PrimaryLangID="en" AltLangID="en" RetransmissionIndicator="false" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
         <POS>
            <Source ISOCountry="ZA" ISOCurrency="ZAR" DisplayCurrency="ZAR" DisplayRate="1.0" FirstDepartPoint="CPT" FinalDestinationPoint="JNB">
               <RequestorID Type="Company" ID="website" ID_Context="ts" TSAffiliateID="<AFFILIATE_ID>" MessagePassword="<AFFILIATE_PASSWORD>">
                  <CompanyName><AFFILIATE_ID></CompanyName>
               </RequestorID>
            </Source>
         </POS>
         <OriginDestinationInformation RefNumber="0">
            <DepartureDateTime>2012-07-26T00:00:00CAT</DepartureDateTime>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="CPT" CodeContext="iata"/>
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="JNB" CodeContext="iata"/>
         </OriginDestinationInformation>
         <OriginDestinationInformation RefNumber="1">
            <DepartureDateTime>2012-07-29T00:00:00CAT</DepartureDateTime>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="JNB" CodeContext="iata"/>
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CPT" CodeContext="iata"/>
         </OriginDestinationInformation>
         <TravelPreferences>
        <FlightTypePref FlightType="Nonstop" DirectAndNonStopOnlyInd="true"/> <!-- This line is optional – include to filter direct flights only -->    
            <CabinPref Cabin="Economy"/>
         </TravelPreferences>
         <TravelerInfoSummary>
            <AirTravelerAvail>
               <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="7" Quantity="0"/>
               <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="8" Quantity="0"/>
               <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="9" Quantity="0"/>
               <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="10" Quantity="1"/>
            </AirTravelerAvail>
         </TravelerInfoSummary>
      </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my Target Url : eg:  http://www.example.com?wsdl

operation name :  search

```
@client = Savon.client(wsdl: ' http://www.example.com?wsdl')

@client.call(:search, message: { 'RefNumber' => '1','DepartureDateTime'=>'2014-09-26T00:00:00CAT','ArrivalDateTime'=>'2012-10-26T00:00:00CAT','OriginLocation'=>'CPT','DestinationLocation'=>'JNB' })
```

***what i am getting :***

```
 (SOAP:Server) No handlers could be found for unmarshalling the SOAP body payload
```

The Soap call i built is correct or i have to build the entire xml of Soap body ?

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

My standard answer:

1. download SoapUI
2. build a valid SOAP request.
3. make sure it works
4. then replicate the request with Ruby/Savon
5. if it still doesn't work, ask again